# Поиск элемента по локатору с индексом

Tags: python, selenium

На сайте есть несколько подборок с одинаковым id, не могу понять где правильно расположить индекс, чтобы осуществлять поиск по нему

```
from BaseApp import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Локаторы
class Locators:
    LOCATOR_COLLECTION1 = (By.XPATH , '//a[@id="collection_link"]')[1]

#Поиск элементов
class SearchHelper(BasePage):

    #Поиск коллекции горячая подборка
    def click_button_collection1(self):
        search_field = self.find_element(Locators.LOCATOR_COLLECTION1)
        search_field.click()
```

Выводится ошибка

```
FAILED test.py::test_collection - TypeError: WebDriver.find_element() takes from 1 to 3 
positional arguments but 27 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в функцию вместо двух параметров пытаетесь передать второй элемент кортежа, являющийся строкой из 27 символов.

```py
from BaseApp import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Локаторы
class Locators:
    LOCATOR_COLLECTION1 = By.XPATH , '//a[@id="collection_link"]'

#Поиск элементов
class SearchHelper(BasePage):

    #Поиск коллекции горячая подборка
    def click_button_collection1(self):
        search_field = self.find_element(*Locators.LOCATOR_COLLECTION1)
        search_field.click()
```

> P.S. Не гарантирую, что вышеописанное заставит ваш код выполнять то, что Вы задумали, но конкретную ошибку, описанную в вопросе, исправит.

Comment: Да, так он будет выбирать первую кнопку с коллекцией, но как мне выбрать 2,3 и тд?

Comment: @АлександрГорчаков, `find_element` -> `find_elements`

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким способом:

```
from BaseApp import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Локаторы
class Locators:
    LOCATOR_COLLECTION = (By.XPATH , '//a[@id="collection_link"]')

#Поиск элементов
class SearchHelper(BasePage):

#Поиск коллекции горячая подборка
    def click_button_collection1(self):
        search_field = self.find_elements(Locators.LOCATOR_COLLECTION)[0]
        search_field.click()
```